# Python xlsxwriter Repaired Records: String properties from /xl/sharedStrings.xml part (Strings)

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I'm creating and writing into an excel file using `xlsxwriter` module. But when I open the excel file, I get this popup:

`We found a problem with some content in 'excel_sheet.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.` If I click Yes, it says `Repaired Records: String properties from /xl/sharedStrings.xml part (Strings)` and then I can see the contents.

I found that this occurs because of the cells I wrote using `write_rich_string`.

`my_work_sheet.write_rich_string(row_no, col_no,format_1, "Some text in format 1", format_2, "Text in format 2", format_1, "Again in format 1")`

If I write it using `write_string` this doesn't occur. `format_1` and `format_2` has font name, color, size and vertical align set.

Can anyone suggest what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to recreate(Thanks to @jmcnamara) the problem and I could figure out where it went wrong.

In my command to `write_rich_string`, sometimes it was trying to format the empty string.

`my_work_sheet.write_rich_string(row_no, col_no,format_1, string_1, format_2, string_2, format_1, string_3)`

I came to know that at some point of time the value of one among `string_1`, `string_2` and `string_3` becomes `''`. Now I use `write_rich_string` only after ensuring they are not `''`.

Comment: I've raised an [bug report issue](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/425) for this in XlsxWriter.

Answer (score 0):

In general that "We found a problem with some content" error/warning from Excel means that an XML element or attribute is malformed in one of the component files in the xlsx file. Again, in general, that means that there is a bug in XlsxWriter or that it has failed to sanitize the user input in some way.

However, in this particular case there isn't enough information to determine what the issue is. I took your snippet of code and turned it into a test program and it works as expected.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('rich_strings.xlsx')
my_work_sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

my_work_sheet.set_column('A:A', 50)

format_1 = workbook.add_format({'color': 'red'})
format_2 = workbook.add_format({'color': 'blue'})

my_work_sheet.write_rich_string(0, 0, 
                                format_1, "Some text in format 1 ", 
                                format_2, "Text in format 2 ", 
                                format_1, "Again in format 1")

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image: example image]

So, you will need to create a small self contained program like the above and submit [a bug report](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/bugs.html#reporting-bugs) to the [XlsxWriter project](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter).

Comment: I accept that the given code snippet can't recreate the issue, but the error message pops up only when i use `write_rich_string`. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: And I accept that the Excel error exists and that it is probably an XlsxWriter bug (I am the author btw) but if you can't reproduce it I can't fix it or provide a workaround. So, you should try to reduce your issue down to a small reproducible program. That way I can investigate and fix it. Otherwise this question will probably go unanswered.